# Chern classes of quaternionic projective plane

Tags: algebraic-topology, quaternions, characteristic-classes

We begin with $\mathbb{H}^2$ and we let $[q_1,q_2]$ denote the class $\{ (q q_1, q q_2), q \in \mathbb{H}, q \neq 0\}$. Under stereographic projection, there is a biejction between this set and $S^4$. We thus a have a quaternionic vector bundle $\mathbb{V} \to S^4$ with fiber isomorphic to $\mathbb{H}$. Under the $\mathbb{C}$ linear isomorphism $\mathbb{H} \cong \mathbb{C}^2$ one can see the bundle as a complex bundle with fiber $\mathbb{C}^2$. What is $c_2(\mathbb{V})$?

According to [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quaternionic_projective_space) the Potryagin class of the quaternionic projective plane $\mathbb{HP}^2$ is given by $(1+v)^6 (1-v)^{-1}$ where $v$ is a generator of $H^4 (\mathbb{HP}^2,\mathbb{Z})$. If I am not mistaken, $\mathbb{V} = \mathbb{HP}^2$. Is this correct? If yes, maybe we could use the relation $(1-p_1(E)+p_2(E))=(1+c_1(E)+c_2(E))(1-c_1(E)+c_2(E))$.

Nevertheless, I am failing to obtain the required class and am not sure how to compute it.

Comment: This bundle doesn't have a complex structure, so what do you mean by Chern classes?

Comment: @JasonDeVito Sorry, hopefully it is clearer now.

Comment: The tangent bundle $T \mathbb{HP}^2$ has no complex structure, because $\mathbb{HP}^2 $ is no  almost complex structure. In fact, (if I remember correctly )the proof that it can't be done proceeds exactly by writing an equations as yours  in the Chern classes and deriving a contradiction. That is certainly how $S^4=\mathbb{HP}^1$ is proven not to be an almost complex manifold.

Comment: @NickL Could you please read the question again. I have edited it.

Comment: To define the Chern classes of a vector bundle it needs to have a complex structure, otherwise the Chern classes are undefined. When you say that "the Pontryagin class of the quaternionic projective plane" you are speaking about the Pontryagin classes of the tangent bundle, because that is the definition of Pontryagin classes of a manifold. It is well-known that this real vector bundle does not have a complex structure, hence there is no way to define the Chern classes of it.

Comment: The fiber is $\mathbb{H}$ and $C^2 \approx \mathbb{H}$. So I guess we could see $\mathbb{V}$ with fiber $C^2$ instead of $\mathbb{H}$, and that makes it a complex vector bundle, doesn't it? @NickL

Comment: No $\mathbb{H}P^n$ admits an almost complex structure (see Massey's paper https://projecteuclid.org/journals/pacific-journal-of-mathematics/volume-12/issue-4/Non-existence-of-almost-complex-structures-on-quaternionic-projective-spaces/pjm/1103036137.full), so $T\mathbb{H}P^n$ cannot admit a quaternionic structure.  Maybe you should try to write down a proof that you "get a quaternioinc vector bundle" - it must go wrong somewhere.